# Date And Time Needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, controllers

Well, I want to display departure and arrival times(with dates) for my flights application.

I had created two fields 'departure' and 'arrival' with data-type datetime.

What methods can be used for these in the controller aand how can i show them in the index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have a `arrival` & `departure` in your `flights` table then

In controller

```
@flights = Flight.all
```

In view

```
<% for flight in @flights%>
  <%= flight.arrival %>
  <%= flight.departure %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<%= flight.arrival.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') %>
```

Or better place a method for formatting in the model.

Comment: I used the below for selecting date:                              <%= date_select(:flight,:departure, {:order => [:day, :month, :year],:prompt => { :day => '-', :month => '-', :year => '-' } }, {:style => "width: 80px"}) %>        Is der any of the same like selecting time.